# Looking for single occurrence between '{' and ':' in a large text

Tags: regex

I'm new to the Regex world, so please be kind on the tantrums :-)

I would like to print only the first occurrence of a string between `{` and `:`.

Example in the following string:

> ({TRIGGER.VALUE}=0 and {Zabbix windows:zabbix[process,discoverer,avg,busy].avg(10m)}>75)
>
> or
>
> ({TRIGGER.VALUE}=1 and {Zabbix windows:zabbix[process,discoverer,avg,busy].avg(10m)}>65)

I want it to output only  `Zabbix windows`

how is that possible?

I tried `{([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*):` it is printing `:` and doing it twice.

Thanks for reading!
Srini

Comment: Use [`\{([\w\s]+):.*`](https://regex101.com/r/0iVuAx/1) and grab Group 1 value. What is the programming language/tool are you using it in? Also, there might be better solutions (like `Regex.Match(s, @"{([\w\s]+):").Groups[1].Value` in C#). Also, I have no idea how [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/p4msBK/1) prints `:` twice.

Comment: Wiktor, thanks a million for a quick reply.  This is exactly what I wanted which works fine here:  https://regex101.com/

but when I try on the Ubuntu Command prompt it does not return anything.  Do I need to do anything special on a Ubuntu command line?

Here is my ubuntu command, copied from what you gave:  egrep '\{([\w]+):.*' ./a.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a PCRE regex with `-o` option (extracting the matches rather than returning the whole lines) to grab the text you need and use `head -1` to only have the first match:

```
s='({TRIGGER.VALUE}=0 and {Zabbix windows:zabbix[process,discoverer,avg,busy].avg(10m)}>75) or ({TRIGGER.VALUE}=1 and {Zabbix windows:zabbix[process,discoverer,avg,busy].avg(10m)}>65)'
echo $s | grep -oP '(?<={)[\w\s]+(?=:)' | head -1
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/f78GJM)

**Pattern details**:

- `(?<={)` - there must be a `{` immediately to the left of the current location
- `[\w\s]+` - 1+ word and/or whitespace chars
- `(?=:)` - there must be a `:` immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Perfect Wiktor!! This did the trick for me :-) . Thanks a MILLION for being very helpful!